# Android phone display broken

Tags: screen, external-display

I'm here to find out alternatives to view the android phone's (Galaxy s3, I9300) display to an external display. I have decided not to repair the display and have move on to use an another phone.

I have come across Micro USB to VGA adaptor. Are there any cheaper ways or even a DIY way to view the port the display? The cell is in otherwise good condition.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of a DIY do you expect? I really can't think of anything other than building your own cable as a DIY solution in this case.

Comment: Probably isn't the correct term.

Comment: Please checkout our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), which links to several related posts.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for an MHL cable.

Here's the cable to connect your Samsung Galaxy S3 to HDMI:

http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/accessories/connectivity/EPL-3FHUBEGSTD

NOTE: 2 Different web sources that I saw right away seem to say it's not a standard MHL cable.  Make sure you check to ensure what you buy is compatible (Or us an official source like above):

http://blog.clove.co.uk/2012/06/08/samsung-galaxy-s3-uses-a-different-mhlhdmi-adapter/

I had the official cable for my Samsung S3 a few years ago and it worked great.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It seems to be like Micro USB to VGA.